# How to fix the select statement returning none value from my db file

Tags: python, select, sqlite

I did spend two days to figure out what happens with my code. I created a database file from my dataframe. The problem is that when i do select statement including a where statement with an integer column i get records returned but when i use a string column, i get none value.

```
con = sqlite3.connect("sqladb.db")

select_str='''select * from sqladb  where age=40 limit 2;'''
results=con.execute(select_str)
for rec in results:
    print(rec)
```

The above code **returns records**.

```
select_str='''select * from sqladb  where sex='Male' limit 2;'''
results=con.execute(select_str)
for rec in results:
    print(rec)
```

The above code is **returning None value** while there are records. The column sex is a string.

I expect the output with records according to my statement.

> Copy from Comment:

```
CREATE TABLE "sqladb" ( "age" INTEGER, "workclass" TEXT, "fnlwgt" INTEGER, "education" TEXT, "education-num" INTEGER, "marital-status" TEXT, "occupation" TEXT, "relationship" TEXT, "race" TEXT, "sex" TEXT, "capital-gain" INTEGER, "capital-loss" INTEGER, "hours-per-week" INTEGER, "native-country" TEXT, "label" TEXT )

(39, ' State-gov', 77516, ' Bachelors', 13, ' Never-married', ' Adm-clerical', ' Not-in-family', ' White', ' Male', 2174, 0, 40, ' United-States', ' <=50K') 
(50, ' Self-emp-not-inc', 83311, ' Bachelors', 13, ' Married-civ-spouse', ' Exec-managerial', ' Husband', ' White', ' Male', 0, 0, 13, ' United-States', ' <=50K') 
(38, ' Private', 215646, ' HS-grad', 9, ' Divorced', ' Handlers-cleaners', ' Not-in-family', ' White', ' Male', 0, 0, 40, ' United-States', ' <=50K')
```

Comment: Show your table definition and some sample rows from it.

Comment: CREATE TABLE "sqladb" ( "age" INTEGER, "workclass" TEXT, "fnlwgt" INTEGER, "education" TEXT, "education-num" INTEGER, "marital-status" TEXT, "occupation" TEXT, "relationship" TEXT, "race" TEXT, "sex" TEXT, "capital-gain" INTEGER, "capital-loss" INTEGER, "hours-per-week" INTEGER, "native-country" TEXT, "label" TEXT )

Comment: (39, ' State-gov', 77516, ' Bachelors', 13, ' Never-married', ' Adm-clerical', ' Not-in-family', ' White', ' Male', 2174, 0, 40, ' United-States', ' <=50K')
(50, ' Self-emp-not-inc', 83311, ' Bachelors', 13, ' Married-civ-spouse', ' Exec-managerial', ' Husband', ' White', ' Male', 0, 0, 13, ' United-States', ' <=50K')
(38, ' Private', 215646, ' HS-grad', 9, ' Divorced', ' Handlers-cleaners', ' Not-in-family', ' White', ' Male', 0, 0, 40, ' United-States', ' <=50K')

Comment: @user2995951: Your data `' Male'` have **leading** blanks!